# Call php value in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to Javascript and I am trying to find a way that I can pass a php value into a javascript/jquery function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#audit_admin_tabs').slideTabs({
            contentAnim: 'slideH',
            contentAnimTime: 600,
            contentEasing: 'easeInOutExpo',
            tabsAnimTime: 300,
            buttonsFunction:'click',
            tabSaveState:true,
            autoHeight:true,
            urlLinking:false        
        });
});
</script>
```

I have a value call $audit_id, the value for which is from a $_GET from the previous page.  I would like to add it to the audit_admin_tabs.  I have tried...

```
div#audit_admin_tabs<? echo $audit_id; ?>
```

But I realise that won't work because php is server side and javascript isn't.  I have also tried echoing the whole function so I can add the php value but that didn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: it should work. PHP can insert something in JavaScript, but the other way around it cannot. Is the file a PHP file?

Comment: yes, it is a php file, I'll try it again incase a I had a typo

Comment: you're using short php tags, that might be the problem, use full `<?php`

Comment: sussed it, the $audit_id had a fullstop in it, changed it for one without and it worked a treat, thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div#audit_admin_tabs<?php echo $_GET['audit_id']; ?>
```

When you want get a get parameter you make it with $_GET['yourparam']

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong tags. It's <?php ?> ... Not <? ?> ... As Franco has mentioned, you need to use $_GET['audit_id'] (or just use $_REQUEST['audit_id'] because that will take care of getting the value from $_GET or $_POST).

To answer your doubt about javascript being client side but PHP being server side :: Yes your understanding is correct, however in this case first PHP will do its magic so the code inside  will get replaced with whatever it should be and then the resulting javascript will be served to the browser. And after that browser will execute that resulting javascript.

So, in short, it should work.